# How to iterate over large sparse array if I need integer keys?

Tags: javascript

I've been using `forEach` but as it turns out, even though the callback function is only called for existing elements, internally the engine pointlessly iterates over the entire array, which can be extremely slow.

Another option would be iterating over `Object.keys()`, but that would give me string keys that I then have to use `parseInt()`, which seems like a pointless waste of time.

Is there any better way of doing this?

Alternatively, I could use a `Map`, but from what I can gather they're not that great for performance.

Comment: Do you actually *want* a sparse array?

Comment: `array.flatMap((x, i) => x ? i : []);`

Comment: @zer00ne `x ? i : []` excludes the indices for [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values, `array.flatMap((x, i) => i)`is suffice, as `flatMap` [does not conflate empty slots](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#array_methods_and_empty_slots).

Comment: @n-- I wasn't sure if OP wanted empties or not and no input array was posted so I just guessed as to what would be the most interesting .

Comment: I would personally suggest using the best fit for the job. In this scenario it seems like `Map` is the best fit. Performance is implementation dependent and might get faster in the future. It does offer all the things you're after. Integer keys, and non-set key/value pairs are not iterated. Regarding speed, you could write a performance test for your exact scenario. Yes, generally speaking `Map` is not the best performer, but if the collection is large and sparse enough it might just be faster than the alternatives.

Answer (score -1):

For this task better to avoid any builtin [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) methods if performance is a concern, as they uses array `length` property for loops. Since arrays are also objects, the fastest way to find the indices in a sparse array will be to use a [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) statement to loop over the object keys and filter the ones that comply with the [specs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#description), i.e. *nonnegative integers*:

```js
const arr = [];

arr[0] = 1;
arr[1] = 1;
arr.push(1);
arr[10] = 1;
arr[100] = 1;
arr[Math.pow(2, 32) - 2] = 1;
arr[-1.2] = 2;
arr[1.2] = 2;
arr['001'] = 2;
arr['abc'] = 2;

const keys = [];
for (let key in arr)
  /^(0|[1-9](\d+)?)$/.test(key) && keys.push(+key);

console.log(arr.length, keys);
```

---

Since the discussion went deep into the [v8 engine source code](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/5fe0aa3bc79c0a9d3ad546b79211f07105f09585/src/builtins/array-foreach.tq#L48), which may raise *implementation-dependency* debates, I will elaborate further my answer.

So, to clarify first that the arrays are objects, thus keys (indices) are object properties, therefore strings, I will cite [the specs](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array-exotic-objects):

> An Array is an [exotic object](https://tc39.es/ecma262#exotic-object)
> that gives special treatment to [array
> index](https://tc39.es/ecma262#array-index) [property
> keys](https://tc39.es/ecma262#sec-object-type) (see
> [6.1.7](https://tc39.es/ecma262#sec-object-type)). A property whose
> [property name](https://tc39.es/ecma262#property-name) is an [array
> index](https://tc39.es/ecma262#array-index) is also called an
> *element*. Every Array has a non-configurable "length" property whose value is always a non-negative [integral
> Number](https://tc39.es/ecma262#integral-number) whose [mathematical
> value](https://tc39.es/ecma262#mathematical-value) is less than 2^32.
> The value of the "length" property is numerically greater than the
> name of every own property whose name is an [array
> index](https://tc39.es/ecma262#array-index); whenever an own property
> of an Array is created or changed, other properties are adjusted as
> necessary to maintain this invariant.

Next, to exclude the *implementation-specific* argument I will link here a more readable, [implementation-agnostic](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/blob/master/packages/core-js/internals/array-iteration.js) source, where we can see how [forEach](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.foreach) and many other methods are implemented in the wild.
Now, it can be seen that the specs, as well as the implementation, relies exclusively on `length` property for array iterations, and there is no dedicated method to get the *filled* keys only, nor the specs neither the implementation handles those in a optimized way, even it seems to be easy enough to implement that, there are no explanations why it is implemented in that way (or are not easily findable). One of guesses is because the [time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) was chosen to be bound to array `length`, i.e. *O(length)*, and not to count of filled keys, and indeed, it would be weird to have the `forEach` method running faster than the generic `for` loop.
Nevertheless, JavaScript is nonrestrictive enough to give us the possibility to handle such optimization in the way we need, once we have a clear understanding how the thing works under the hood.
To summarize, we can handle this in a performant way as follows:

- Obviously, use the `for...in` loop above right there were it is needed.
- Go further and create a function, then put it in global scope (dirty), extend the `Array.prototype` (unsafe) or create a new type object inherited from `Array` and assign that function to it (safe).
- Those anxious about or disgusted by `for..in` loop may go even further and use some exotic solutions based on [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy), as in the example below, which may be even more performant:

```js
const getArray = (() => {
    const KEYS = Symbol();
    const keys = function () {
        return Object.freeze([...this[KEYS]].sort((a, b) => a - b));
    };
    const set = function (ids, fn, self, key, receiver) {
        /^(0|[1-9](\d+)?)$/.test(key) && fn.call(ids, +key);
        return Reflect[this](self, key, receiver);
    };
    return () => {
        const ids = new Set();
        return Object.defineProperties(new Proxy([], {
            set: set.bind('set', ids, ids.add),
            deleteProperty: set.bind('deleteProperty', ids, ids.delete)
        }), {indices: {get: keys}, [KEYS]: {value: ids}});
    };
})();

const arr = getArray();

arr[0] = 1;
arr[1] = 1;
arr.push(1);
arr[10] = 1;
arr[100] = 1;
arr[Math.pow(2, 32) - 2] = 1;
arr[-1.2] = 2;
arr[1.2] = 2;
arr['001'] = 2;
arr['abc'] = 2;

console.log(arr.length, arr.indices);
```

Comment: Not fully spec-compliant, overkill in practice, and still goes through strings – which is what the asker mentioned they want to avoid.

Comment: @Ry There are no `number` keys in objects, the array numeric indices are just an abstraction. You can safely set an index with `array['1']` or whatever nonnegative integer string.

Comment: Yes, the point is that parsing the integer back out of the string is overhead (compared to looping using an incrementing integer over a non-sparse array).

Comment: And how that is overhead if array is implemented on top of object and [internally](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/objects/js-array.h) the keys are strings? Or do you suggesting that the index returned in the handler of `forEach` method is the raw array index?

Comment: How does your link show that (in V8) the keys of an array are internally strings? Here’s `forEach`: https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/5fe0aa3bc79c0a9d3ad546b79211f07105f09585/src/builtins/array-foreach.tq#L84-L85

Comment: @Ry- Yes, on that link is not so obvious, one should dig deeper to find out that, but it is very obvious in the [forEach](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/5fe0aa3bc79c0a9d3ad546b79211f07105f09585/src/builtins/array-foreach.tq#L48)  source you have pointed, even if one cannot read the code can realize it from the comments: `k is guaranteed to be a positive integer, hence ToString is side-effect free and HasProperty/GetProperty do the conversion inline.`, i.e. the computed index integer `k` is converted to string for `has/get` operations on array object.

Comment: That’s the deoptimized version. See [line 114–117](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/5fe0aa3bc79c0a9d3ad546b79211f07105f09585/src/builtins/array-foreach.tq#L114-L117).

Comment: @Ry- No, that is a regular one, and what you linked is a *special case*. I've built a list of *breakpoints* to give a better understanding on the *flow*, but since there are many links it does not fit in one comment...

Comment: ...so here it is: [1](https://github.com/v8/v8/tree/main/src/builtins/array-foreach.tq#L116)
[2](https://github.com/v8/v8/tree/main/src/builtins/array-foreach.tq#L75)
[2.1](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/objects/js-array.tq#L82)
[2.2](https://v8.dev/blog/fast-properties#elements-or-array-indexed-properties)
[3](https://github.com/v8/v8/tree/main/src/builtins/array-foreach.tq#L117)
[4](https://github.com/v8/v8/tree/main/src/builtins/array-foreach.tq#L122)
[5](https://github.com/v8/v8/tree/main/src/builtins/array-foreach.tq#L41)

Comment: It’s both a special case and the *common* case, including for arrays with holes.

Comment: Frankly, those sources doesn't really matters anymore as there is just a `v8` specific optimization of how to access and store underlying, low-level data memory structures, while both special and common cases are O(length) time complexity, I explained it already in the answer. At the end of the day is that the array keys are stored as strings and the `for..in` loop is by no means overkill, indeed much more performant in case of *large sparse arrays* OP requirement than a `for` incremental loop or any other builtin array iterator.